# android:Page curl animation effect

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

If anybody have a Page Curl Effect example Demo so please give me link for this

Thanks

Comment: To do animation , pls refer my blog,http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.com/2011/04/performing-animation-in-android.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardik ,there are already tons of questions out there see this

http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=FOq&channel=cs&q=page+curl+android+stackoverflow&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=

or refer this project [android-page-curl](http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/)