# How can I do the paper peel effect in Android?

Tags: android, titanium

When making an Android app, I want to have the paper peel effect that's popular on the iPhone where the corner looks pulled back and the user and tough and drag to "fold" up the page.

I'm using Titanium, if that matters. How can I do that?

Comment: Not Titanium But i have something here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727276/androidpage-curl-animation-effect

Comment: RenderScript? I know people were using it unofficially pre-honeycomb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this link will surely help you out......

https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/

sorry, the above link was for android, in titanium add this line to your view

**transition:Titanium.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.CURL_UP**